# Is there a delphi ScrollInView equivalent in Free Pascal?

Tags: freepascal

I have a ScrollBox and I'm adding controls to it at runtime. However, when the controls exceed the ScrollBox height, I want the ScrollBox to scroll all the way to the bottom so that the newly added controls are visible.

Doing some research, I've found something called "ScrollInView" for delphi. Seeing how many (quite a lot) of Delphi methods/functions are available in Free Pascal, do you know of any equivalent to this particular one? If not, can you help me achieve my goal (Auto-scrolling the ScrollBox to the bottom) with a different solution?

Thanks in advance,

Oscar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
    with TEdit.Create(Self) do
    begin
        Parent := ScrollBox1;
        Left := 10;
        Top := ScrollBox1.ControlCount * 40;
        ScrollBox1.VertScrollBar.Position := Top;
    end;
end;
```

And here is hte simple implementation of the `ScrollInView` method:

```
TScrollBoxHelper = class helper for TScrollBox
    procedure ScrollInView(AControl: TControl);
end;

implementation

procedure TScrollBoxHelper.ScrollInView(AControl: TControl);
begin
    if AControl.Parent = Self then
    begin
        Self.VertScrollBar.Position := AControl.Top;
        Self.HorzScrollBar.Position := AControl.Left;
    end;
end;
```

Usage:

```
procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
    ScrollBox1.ScrollInView(ScrollBox1.Controls[3]);
end;
```

Comment: Thanks for the guidance, doing ScrollBox1.VertScrollBar.Position:= ScrollBox1.ControlCount *40 did the trick ^_^ . That's 2 answers I've gotten from you Abelisto, next time I'll make sure to message you before asking :p . Many Thanks!